# Applying continuous operators to functions defined by parameter integrals.

Tags: analysis, integration

Let $T\in \mathcal{L}(\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^{n}))$.

For fixed $f\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^{2n})$, define $g(x):=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x,y)\, dy$. Note that this implies that $g$ is also Schwartz.

Is it true that:

$$(Tg)(x):=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}T_xf(x,y) \, dy $$?

I think I have proven this if f is compactly supported (which is all I really need for my application), but it would be nice to know how general this fact is.

Comment: If you use compact support to eliminate boundary values from integration by parts, it should also work for Schwartz functions.